# Stored procedure access rights

Tags: mysql

I am completely new to `MySql`.

Consider this scenario :

Admin created multiple users in a `ApplicationUser` table, also he created some stored procedures.

Now, is it possible to assign rights to these users to run these stored procedures ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See [`GRANT Syntax`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html), there you can find a lot of examples too (in your case: `GRANT EXECUTE`). Some remarks: The mysql grant system is a little bit uncomfortable, as you can only allow (not forbid) things, and there are no user groups. You have to grant access for each user. If you want to allow access to all procedures but one, you have to create n-1 grants per user (if you want to allow access to all procedures, one grant to all procedures per user is enough though).

Comment: @Solarflare Hi, I am talking about a normal application user and not a db user.

Comment: Ah sorry I think I misread that. Well, MySQL only supports the grant system. If your user in your app is not the user in the database (what you might consider), you have to check the permissions in your app (around the code that may or may not execute the stored procedure). You may also send the username as a parameter to all procedures and check it first (then the procedure technically gets executed, but returns an error).

Comment: @Solarflare Ok, thats what I was thinking.